# How to set a value on a React TextField with handlechange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield, react-hook-form

I need to set a value after pressing a button on this textfield :

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  inputProps={{ maxLength: 75 }}
  key="nomeSocial"
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="Nome Social"
  name="nomeSocial"
  onChange={(handleChange)}
  value={values.nomeSocial}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

I've tried to set the value by the comand

```js
document.getElementsByName("nomeSocial")[0].value = "..."
```

but the field get this way:
[image]

and when I click somewhere the input gets empty.

is there any way to change a value of a input by javascript and have the TextField recognize it as if someone had typed it?

Comment: You should not be messing with the DOM (e.g. `document.getElementByName(.....).value`) but instead working with the React model.

The value displayed in the TextField is the value of `values.nomeSocial`, and each time something is typed into the field `handleChange()` fires.  So what is the code of `handleChange` ?  Please provide its code.  Also provide us with the definition of `values`: is it a state variable in this component or a prop or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot use onChange like that**

First, you should create a state for your value
Then set this value prop into the **TextField** component
And use the onChange properly with the right syntax to make a controlled input field in React.

See the following code:

```html
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const ControlledField = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

const handleChage = (e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value)
}

return (
  <TextField
      label="Enter Text"
      variant="outlined"
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
    />
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
onChange={(handleChange)}
```

to:

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
```

"e" is the change event, so you need to add it to your `handleChange()` function.